# Websphere messaging queue

Tags: jms, websphere-8, spring-jms

I am new to write code for Websphere mq. I need sample code to use existing Websphere mq to send request and receive response. Please help me. Advance thankd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of samples are shipped with IBM MQ. Look into `<mq installation>\tools\` directory (on Windows) for samples developed in C,C++, Java, C# and number of other languages.

Comment: I am using Websphere server 8.5. I am unable to find <mq installation>\tools\ directory. Please share the online tutorials to use IBM Websphere MQ.

Comment: Oh. You mentioned WebSphere MQ. Hence my answer was for MQ. But I am sure there will be samples in WAS installation also